# Box2D collision causes huge FPS drop

Tags: html, canvas, box2d, collision, frame-rate

I'm playing with [Box2Dweb](http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/) and HTML5 canvas, and are experiencing some odd behaviour.
I have one dynamic body and one static body, in the world. I can control the dynamic one with my keyboard.

But as soon as these two collide, I dip from 60 fps to 17, and I cannot move the dynamic body any more (due to the lag, it bearly moves).

I have try profiling it using Firebug, and you can see the result here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLHvG.png

As you can see, it's almost just Box2D taking up time here; my own rendering/clearing/processing functions aren't even listed until like 0.1% in the table.

If you want any sample-code, tell me! I have found other people with the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979069/box2d-static-body-collision-performance-issue) and [here](http://box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=8671), but they didn't get any answer. So I'm giving it another try!

Comment: Do you use some collisions handler?

Comment: Yes, I'm creating a ContactListener. However, I've tried commenting it out, but it makes no differance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem!
It is related to the PPM (Pixels Per Meter).

It turns out I was setting it to pretty low (32), and when I increased it to 192, everything runs smoothly again! Thank god. Hope that this can help other people!

Comment: do you have any idea why PPM would result in a low FPS?

Comment: Actually no. My guess is that it's related to the size of your game world as well. Having a very low PPM means that you can fit "more pixels" in your world. That is, simulate greater amounts of data.